# Spark doesn't recognize the column name in SQL query while can output it to a dataset

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm applying the SQL query like that:

```
s"SELECT *  FROM my_table_joined WHERE (timestamp > '2022-01-23' and writetime is not null and acceptTimestamp is not null)"
```

and I'm getting the error message like that.

```
warning: there was one deprecation warning (since 2.0.0); for details, enable `:setting -deprecation' or `:replay -deprecation'
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "accepttimestamp" does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "mf_joined.acceptTimestamp".
  Position: 103
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:108)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:61)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:226)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:344)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:221)
  at $$$e76229fa87b6865de321c5274e52c2f9$$$$w$getDFFromJdbcSource(<console>:1133)
  ... 326 elided
```

If I omit `acceptTimestamp` like that:

```
s"SELECT *  FROM my_table_joined WHERE (timestamp > '2022-01-23' and writetime is not null)"
```

I'm getting the data as below:

```
+-------------------+----------+----+------------------+-----------------+---+-----+------+----------+---------------+-------+-----------------------+----------+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+---------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+---+------------------+-----+----+----+------------------+---+
|timestamp          |flags     |type|lon               |lat              |alt|speed|course|satellites|digital_twin_id|unit_id|unit_ts                |name      |unit_type|measure_units|access_level|uid            |placement|stale|start              |writetime              |acceptTimestamp|delayWindowEnd|DiffInSeconds|time               |hour               |max|min|mean              |count|max2|min2|mean2             |rnb|
+-------------------+----------+----+------------------+-----------------+---+-----+------+----------+---------------+-------+-----------------------+----------+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+---------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+---+------------------+-----+----+----+------------------+---+
```

please note `acceptTimestamp` is here!

So how I should handle this column in my query to make it taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception, it seems this is related to Postgres not Spark. If you look at the error message you got, the column name is folded to lowercase `accepttimestamp` whereas in your query the `T` is in uppercase `acceptTimestamp`.

To make the column name case-sensitive for Postgres, you need to use double-quotes. Try this:

```
val query = s"""SELECT * FROM my_table_joined 
    WHERE   timestamp > '2022-01-23' 
    and     writetime is not null 
    and     "acceptTimestamp" is not null"""
```